# Combination of 2 tables into one query

Tags: postgresql

i have 2 tables Sales and Employees per attached in postgresql.
I need to calculate:
Query that returns top 4 employees with the most high sales on 2015. In addition, sales of employess that have been already left the company should be under employee number 999
Thanks in advance foy your help

[Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bMCN.jpg)
[image: Employess]

Comment: Please read this post and its accepted answer : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Sooo.. you want us to do your homework for you? What have you done so far ?

Comment: I have tried to solve it without sucess :(. I'm new in the SQL field and in programming at all. i hoped that from the answer i would be able to learn. I did one SQL course on line. However, i think it is not enough. I would be happy to get recommended SQL course that could help me to figure out those kind of questions. Thanks

Comment: *I have tried to solve it without sucess* So copy/paste what you did and what you are stuck on. Also, we don't do your typing I'm afraid :: images of data are useless and will be ignored. You need to copy/paste data (as formatted text) too. You could try using http://rextester.com or http://dbfiddle.uk to setup your tables and experiment.

Comment: Please read this article: https://academy.vertabelo.com/blog/oracle-top-n-queries-absolute-beginners/ Top-N query explained for absolute beginners

Comment: Thanks a lot!it seems that the ecademy has lots of excercises. Thats exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended SQL Already Tested:**

```
SELECT  
s.employee_id, emp.first_name,  
emp.last_name, s.department,  
sum(s.num_of_products) as total_product,  
sum(s.total_price) as total_price,  
s.branch_id, s.branch_city,  
s.date  
FROM sales s  
JOIN employees emp  
ON s.employee_id = emp.employee_id  
WHERE date_part('year',s.date) = '2014'  
-- '2014' is year depend on the input ex. '2015'  
GROUP BY s.employee_id, emp.first_name,emp.last_name,  
s.department, s.branch_id, s.branch_city, s.date  
-- add non aggregate function (sum,count,max,etc) field to group by if you want to show the field.  
-- not add in group by cause error 'field must appear in group by'
ORDER BY total_product  
-- order by total_product based on total_product  
-- order by for choose order by product or price using alias  
-- order by without alias ORDER BY sum(s.num_of_products)  
-- order by will be error caused error if use num_of_products  
-- order by total_price if the TOP 4 based on total_price  
LIMIT 4;   
-- top 4  
-- top n => LIMIT n
```

Comment: Hope this query help you, if you still not understand we can discuss in comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Please Mark as answer if you feel this is the right ans

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. it did helped me a lot. However,1. why did u put 2014 if the question is on 2015 year (i'm nor sure that i have fully understood your comment)? 2.I don't see that u have mantined the last part of 999:..."in addition, sales of employess that have been already left the company should be under employee number 999 Thanks in advance foy your help". Thanks again